# Problem with similarity of triangles and median.

Tags: geometry, median

I have the next problem:

In the next image, MN // AB, PN = NC, QM = 8, BM = 6 and MC = 9. Calculate PM.

[image: Probrem]

First I tried to find similarities in the triangles formed by the parallel sides, ABC and MNC.

So if NC = 9k, AN = 6K then AP = 3K. Then I tried to play with the angles, maybe angle ABC = 90 so there is a 6-8-10 triangle or angle PMC = 90 so MN = PN = NC but was unable to find anything else.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: BM = 6 and BM = 9 ??????????

Comment: @Arashium oopsie. Fixed now.

Comment: MN =P??????? PMC = 90???????????

Comment: Yeah, there PMC is an angle, and the the other one is fixed.

Comment: How did you conclude MN = PN ?

Comment: Also, if ABC=90 then NMC=90 then PMC cannot be 90

Comment: I was mentioning 2 cases I was trying to find. MN would be the same as PN if PMC was a rectangle angle.

Comment: you mentioned PN = NC at first. so do you mean PN = NC = MN?

Comment: PN = NC is part of the problem, but if the triangle was rectangle, PN and NC would be the same as the median, so MN.

Comment: ABC=NMC so PMC>ABC. it means that if ABC=90, then it is impossible for PMC to be 90

Comment: Yes, I was mentioning 2 different cases. I was not able to find any of those anyway. The only things I'm sure is about the similarity and the relation at the bottom.

Comment: see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got what you mean. Note that there is no need to any extra assumption. The solution is as following:

Lets call

$$x=NC$$

$$\frac{AN}{NC}=\frac{6}{9}$$

so $$AN=\frac{2}{3}x$$

and $$PA=\frac{1}{3}x$$

There is another similarity between triangles PQA and PMN

Therefore:

$$\frac{PQ}{QM}=\frac{\frac{1}{3}x}{\frac{2}{3}x}$$

$$\frac{PQ}{8}=\frac{\frac{1}{3}x}{\frac{2}{3}x}$$

$$PQ=4$$

Comment: Wow. Thank you. Now that you showed me how to solve it, it looks way easier than some minutes ago lol. Awesome.